# Can't compile php 5.3 on Centos 6

Tags: centos, compiling, php

I need enable php-fpm on php 5.3.29 to Centos 6, I have this error while running the `./configure` script:

```
...    
config.status: creating sapi/fpm/php-fpm.conf
config.status: creating sapi/fpm/init.d.php-fpm
config.status: creating sapi/fpm/php-fpm.service
config.status: creating sapi/fpm/php-fpm.8
config.status: creating sapi/fpm/status.html
config.status: error: cannot find input file: sapi/cgi/php-cgi.1.in
```

The command `./configure` is:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/php-5.3.29 \
--with-zlib-dir \
--with-freetype-dir \
--enable-mbstring \
--with-libxml-dir=/usr \
--enable-soap \
--enable-calendar \
--with-curl \
--with-mcrypt \
--with-zlib \
--with-gd \
--disable-rpath \
--enable-inline-optimization \
--with-bz2 \
--with-zlib \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-sysvsem \
--enable-sysvshm \
--enable-pcntl \
--enable-mbregex \
--with-mhash \
--enable-zip \
--with-pcre-regex \
--with-mysql \
--with-pdo-mysql \
--with-mysqli \
--with-png-dir=/usr \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--with-openssl \
--with-fpm-user=apache \
--with-fpm-group=apache \
--with-libdir=lib64 \
--enable-ftp \
--with-kerberos \
--with-gettext \
--with-gd \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib/ \
--enable-fpm
```

Comment: Does [Run PHP Applications under CGI with Apache on CentOS 6](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/apache/run-php-applications-under-cgi-with-apache-on-centos-6) help?  I think you're missing `yum install php-cgi`.

Comment: Thanks, i've installed `php-cgi` but the error is the same...

Comment: Please provide the output of `rpm -qa | grep php` and advise us whether you want a SxS (Side by Side) install of php, or an upgrade of the system wide PHP. [SxS Install](http://superuser.com/questions/682378/how-to-install-php-5-3-on-centos-6), or [Upgrade PHP](https://linuxmoz.com/php-5-3-centos-6-install-upgrade/).  In my opinion, there is no reason to compile when a package already exists.

Comment: As for the FPM Module see: [Apache + PHP-FPM + MySQL on CentOS 6.5](https://hrace009.wordpress.com/2014/11/29/apache-php-fpm-mysql-on-centos-6-5/)